# how do you prevent fancy box's close button from auto hiding?

Tags: fancybox-3

I have the following iframe situation.

```
<a _ngcontent-c27="" data-color="red" data-fancybox="id_ALPHA" data-opacity="1" data-src="https://startalkcreate.org/resource-modal/" data-type="iframe" href="javascript:;">
                <span _ngcontent-c27="" style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px;">Browse Resources Repository</span>
            </a>
```

It nicely pops the windows the facny way. But the close ( dismissing [X] )  button disappears after a few seconds. The not-so-savy users have a difficult time closing that pop up and end up using the back button. Is there a way to make sure the x to always  stay visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idleTime` option to disable auto hiding, simply add `data-idle-time="false"` to your link.

Comment: Hey Janis, do you happen to know the instructions that prevent the iframe from auto-sizing? I would like the iframe to pop full size ( with some room ofcourse to place the close button [X ]).

Comment: Auto-sizing is enabled by default - the script resizes iframe to match content dimensions. If you want to have 100% width (and/or height), then you can disable preloading and set custom dimensions either using CSS or JS, see this demo https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/RYXOeK?editors=1100 and you can find more samples here https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#iframe